# Client-side encryption of data, but the server can also add data without reading stored data

Tags: encryption, web-application, key-generation, key-exchange, client-side

For a new application I'd like to store messages for each user's account on a centralized server.

The user accesses the application through a SPA javascript web app through their browser.

These messages:

- Should be unreadable by the server
- Are readable only by the user themselves (not other users)
- Can be added by the server (readable only transiently before encrypting)
- Can be added by the user (then encrypted and sent to the server)

I'm using libsodium and my proposed solution is to:

- Generate a randomly generated salt client-side using `randombytes_random`
- Derive a key from their plain-text login password, on account creation, using `crypto_pwhash` and the previously generated salt
- Use this key as a seed to generate a public and secret keypair using `crypto_box_seed_keypair`
- Store the public key and salt on the server (sent via secure transport)
- Store the secret key on the client in localStorage (I'd like to avoid the user having to enter their password too often)
- Regenerate the secret key on login by retrieving the salt from the server and recreating the seed to generate the keypair
- Client encrypts with the public key using `crypto_box_seal`
- Server encrypts with the stored public key using `crypto_box_seal`
- Client decrypts with the public key and secret key using `crypto_box_seal_open`

Is this scheme vulnerable?

I'm worried about storing the secret key in localStorage.

Does it instead make sense to:

- Store the seed in localStorage
- Generate another salt that is then retrieved from the server
- Hash that together with the original seed to generate a new seed
- Use the new seed to generate the keypair?

Comment: Why using asymetric encryption? An AES key should be enough for what you need.
About the store of the key, most fo the end to end encryption app I saw put the key in the URL after a '#' (which is not send to the server)

Comment: I'd like the server (controlled by me) to not be able to read the stored data. But would also like it to be able to add stored data from a third-party. Which means that it would have to read unencrypted messages temporarily before encrypting them with a public key and storing them. I don't think I can do that with an AES key? Otherwise the server would also be able to decrypt the messages

Comment: I think I don't understand well the case but is it not easier to make the third party encrypt its data at the client side and send them already encrypted to your server ?

Comment: Unfortunately not possible in this use case. I'd like the user to be able to add messages via SMS, which means that I need to process the response from a third party (Twilio). So there will be some moment where the message is seen in plain-text before it is encrypted and stored in the server.

Comment: So your approach is to encrypt the received datat with a public key but whos generated this key ? the server or the client ?. If it's you, how do you manage to send the private key to the user ? If it's the user, why he cannot encrypt its message and send it encrypted through sms

Comment: The client generates the keypair. The user is non-technical, so any encryption has to happen behind-the-scenes. Their interface to the server via sms should look just like texting normally to a phone number.

Comment: Okay the client is non-technical but if you assume that he has to generate a keypair, I guess that somewhere he execute some code under your control (an app ?). So why not using your app to display an user friendly interface which let him type whatever he wants like a regular sms, but your app encrypt it and send it as the content of an SMS

Comment: Yep, that app interface is the normal way they would enter data. But the sms would be a more convenient interface if they didn't want to visit a website, with the tradeoff that the server may temporarily see the data. I'm looking for the sms to be a different way to input data to be stored on the server. There is never any SMS sent back to the user, or to other people.